# Electromagnetic wave intensity doubt

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

If we consider a source, radiating electromagnetic radiation in all directions, intensity falls off as 1/r^2, and thus electric field amplitude falls off as 1/r. But if I consider exactly one wave emanating from the source, there is no way that that one day can lose energy and therefore it's amplitude of electric field has to be a constant. Whats wrong with my analysis

Answer (score 1):

The energy is spread out over  a larger surface area as the wave expands. The electric field squared is proportional to the energy *density*, not the energy. So as the wave expands, the energy per unit area goes down, but the area goes up, in a way that keeps the total energy of the wave fixed.

Comment: If electric field square is proportional energy density, that means it will decrease with increasing in distance , as energy density decreases with distance. But for a lone wave the electric field is a constant right

Comment: Only if by "lone wave" you mean "plane wave." If the wave is spreading out at all, the electric field is not constant.